how do i use paths to a folder in dropbox in python?
I'm trying to load data from a folder on dropbox into python on vscode. I'm pretty sure I know how what the filepath should be (file_path = "/Users/USERNAME/Dropbox/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/FILE.tsv") but i don't understand how vscode can connect to dropbox to access it.
also here is the snippet of code where I use it
import pandas as pd
file_path = "/Users/USERNAME/Dropbox/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/FILE.tsv")     
products = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t', dtype={XXXX})

I've tried using this dropbox for python developers thing, but I don't really think I understand how to use it properly. I also don't know where to find my user access token, which it seems to require. I've never worked with dropbox before so any advice would be super appreciated!

Can you access the file using that pathname from the shell? It should work the same from Python. File access is handled by by the operating system, not the language.

Also, what happens when you run (the equivalent of) this code? Does it error out? give you a blank DataFrame? That would be nice to have in an [edit].

To clarify a bit, the "Dropbox for Python" SDK that you linked to is for connecting to the Dropbox API, over the internet. That would enable you to access a Dropbox account remotely, using an access token. That would be an alternative to accessing the contents of the local Dropbox folder, like you are trying to do in your code snippet. If you do already have the data locally available, accessing it locally probably is the simpler/better option.

import pandas as pd



products = pd.read_csv("//Users//USERNAME//Dropbox//FOLDER1//FOLDER2//FOLDER3//FILE.tsv", sep='\t', dtype={XXXX})

Can u try it please ? I hope it will be work :)

This answer makes no sense. Since when do you use // to separate directories?

I think they mixed up escaped backslashes \\ with double forward slashes //.
